# Apache Spark RDD persistence only when exception is thrown

Tags: apache-spark

I was considering caching one of my RDDs that took longer to process only if an exception was thrown and the job was killed. If I run the job again, I'd like it to continue where it failed, avoiding the processing of that RDD again.

Does it make sense? Would the same job start a different Spark context not being able to locate that cached RDD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cached data is lost when a Spark program exits. Checkpoint may be an option, though, as it will save the RDD to disk. [Check here](http://alvincjin.blogspot.com/2014/12/cache-vs-checkpoint-in-spark.html) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. Checkpoint is a powerful feature but I think it doesn't fit my scenario where I'd like to avoid re-computation of the same job after failure. I believe checkpoint triggers another job after the job is finished successfully, and in my case the job failed.